# I cannot modify a variable after an async mongoose query in Express route. The variable does not change

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I have an empty array `let last_activity = []` that I want to modify based on what comes back from a Mongoose query inside of an Express route, although currently I'm just trying to change it to `[1, 2, 3]` for troubleshooting purposes. I've tried the following:

`const thread = Thread.findOne({id: ThreadId}).then(() => {last_activity = [1, 2, 3]})`

(inside of `async` function): 
`const thread ) await Thread.findOne({id: threadId}).exec();
last_activity = [1, 2, 3]`

This works, but obiovusly will not work when I want to actually use what comes back from the query: 

`const thread = Thread.findOne({id: threadId}).exec();
last_activity = [1, 2, 3];`

Here is the complete route handler:

```
    app.get('/api/threads/last_activity', (req, res) => {
    const threads = req.user.social.threads;
    let last_activity = [];
    threads.map(async threadId => {
        const message = await Thread.findOne({ id: threadId }).slice('messages', -1).exec();
        last_activity = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
    });
    console.log(last_activity); //Logs [] to console
    res.send(last_activity);
});
```

I assume I'm missing something regarding how Node handles async code. Thanks a bunch in advance for any help!

Comment: The problem might be elsewhere in the program. `last_activity` on your first example do gets set properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Robert. I've added all the code from my route handler in my question.

Comment: The `threads.map(async () => foo)` part (assuming `threads` is array) creates bunch of promises and within each of those promises `last_activity` is being set to [1, 2, 3]. For console.log and res.send, you are not waiting for the promises to resolve, they are being ran immediately each of the promises have been created in map. I am confused to what you want to be inside of `last_activity` in non debugging cases to suggest solution.

Comment: threads is an array of strings, each representing an id i use to search for a Thread in my database. Each Thread contains an array of messages, and I am grabbing the last message. I want `last_activity` to be an array containg the last message of each thread. So, instead of `last_activity = [1, 2, 3]`, I want something like `last_activity = [...last_activity, message]`, so that in the end, `last_activity` is an array of messages. Also, i thought that by using `async` and `await` or `.then(() => foo)` I was in fact waiting for the promises to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/api/threads/last_activity', (req, res) => {
    const threads = req.user.social.threads;
    let last_activity = [];

    Promise.all(
        threads.map(async threadId => {
            const message = await Thread.findOne({ id: threadId })
                                        .slice('messages', -1)
                                        .exec();
            last_activity.push(message);
        })
    )
    .then(() =>
    {
        console.log(last_activity); //Logs [] to console
        res.send(last_activity);
    })
    .catch((err) =>
    {
        //...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked flawlessly! I've never used `Promise.all` before, so I suppose I'll have to look into that. Thanks a bunch for the help. I've accepted your answer.